# Css changes not applying with php

Tags: php, css

Im just trying to add a border and background color to my php gallery but the changes don't apply on refresh. I also have cleared the cache.

I have tried:
adding "color:red;" to the paragraph and header tags,
making a new class called "border" and adding that to the paragraph and header tag,
 and editing their CSS classes all to no avail.

```
echo '<a href="#";">
                  <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].');"></div>
                  <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                  <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                </a>';
.gallery-container a div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 205px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-color:black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.gallery-container a h3 {
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #111;
  padding-top: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  border-color:black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.gallery-container a p {
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #111;
  padding-top: 4px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-color:black;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

I expect a border to be added, but the actual output is nothing

Comment: You can't mix php and css like this in the same file...  If these are different files, then you must link the css stylesheet to the html.

Comment: try to set your css in to your php echo command and set around your css command the `<style>` tags.

Comment: The css is in a different file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're not actually `echo`ing the css string so nothing happens with it at all. The client doesn't receive it, and `css` is something that is interpenetrated by the browser.

However, php `echo` just gives the browser text which in your case it assumes to be `html` so you can't just put the `css` there without wrapping it in a `<style>`.

**fixed:**

```
echo '<a href="#">
       <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')"</div>
       <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
       <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
       </a>';


echo "<style>

    .gallery-container a div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 205px;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      border-color:black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .gallery-container a h3 {
      font-family: Catamaran;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #111;
      padding-top: 16px;
      line-height: 26px;
      border-color:black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .gallery-container a p {
      font-family: Catamaran;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #111;
      padding-top: 4px;
      line-height: 20px;
      border-color:black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
    </style>"
```

In case the `css` is in a different file, then you need to make sure you are fetching it using the `html`. From the code you posted fetching it can be achieved like this:

`page_style.css` would be the file with the css.

**php code:**

```
echo '<a href="#">
       <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')"</div>
       <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
       <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
       </a>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page_style.css">
    ';
```